# Jetty: Hold Connection till a remote callback request is received

Tags: java, web-services, jetty

I have an asynchronous service, call it A, which returns ack immediately to the caller, and when the response is ready (may take up to 100 seconds) it will be returned by HTTP-calling the client (callback).

Service A is a black-box for me.

I want to create another service on a different machine, call it B, which will be a proxy to service A. Service B should hold the connection of every request to it, then call service A. once the callback from service A is received, the connection to service B releases with a response.

This way I'll be able to have service A act synchronously.

Can I implement service B using Jetty? How?

Comment: What have you tried?  What does your code currently look like?  What technology within Jetty are you needing to use?

Comment: I tried to implement a 'while' loop in the doPost() that checks a status of the jobId in a static HashMap, every 100 ms. The status is updated when the async callback arrives. This works just fine but the problem is that I keep a working thread for every request that I "hold", until it is being released.